# Simulation from a nested glmer model

Tags: lme4

I'm having a problem generating simulations from a 3 level glmer model when conditioning on the random effects (I'm actually using predict via bootMer but the problem is the same).

This works:

```
library(lme4)
fit1 =   glmer(cbind(incidence, size - incidence) ~ period + (1 | herd),
                                            data = cbpp, family = binomial)
simulate(fit1, re.form=NULL)
```

This fails:

```
cbpp$bigherd = rep(1:7, 8)
fit2 =   glmer(cbind(incidence, size - incidence) ~ period + (1 | bigherd / herd),
                             data = cbpp, family = binomial)
simulate(fit2, re.form=NULL)    
Error: No random effects terms specified in formula
```

Many thanks for any ideas.

## Update

Ben, many thanks for your help below, really appreciate it. I wonder if I can impose on you again.

What I want to do is simulate predictions on the response scale and I'm not sure if I can use your work around? Or if there is an alternative to what I'm doing. Thank you!

This works as expected, but is not conditional on random effects:

```
FUN = function(.){
    predict(., type="response")
}
bootMer(fit2, FUN, nsim=3)$t
```

This doesn't work, as would be expected given above problem:

```
bootMer(fit2, FUN, nsim=3, use.u=TRUE)$t
```

As far as I can see, I can't pass `re.form` to `bootMer`.

Does the alternative below result in simulated predictions conditional on random effects without passing `use.u` to `bootMer`?

```
FUN = function(.){
    predict(., type="response", re.form=~(1|herd:bigherd) + (1|bigherd))
}
bootMer(fit2, FUN, nsim=10)$t
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what's going on yet, but here are two workarounds that *do* work:

```
simulate(fit2, re.form=lme4:::reOnly(formula(fit2)))
simulate(fit2, re.form=~(1|herd:bigherd) + (1|bigherd))
```

There must be something going wrong with the expansion of the "slash" term, because this doesn't work:

```
simulate(fit2, re.form=~(1|bigherd/herd))
```

I've posted this as an [lme4 issue](https://github.com/lme4/lme4/issues/335)

These workarounds don't work for `bootMer` (which only takes the `use.u` argument, not `re.form`) in the current CRAN release (1.1-9).

It is fixed in the development version on Github (1.1-10): `devtools::install_github("lme4/lme4")` will install it, if you have compilation tools installed.

In the meantime you could just go ahead and implement your own parametric bootstrap (for parametric bootstrapping, `bootMer` is actually a very thin wrapper around `simulate()/[`refit()`or`update()`]/`FUN`). Much of the complication has to do with parallel computation (you'd have to add some of it back in if you want parallel computation in your own PB implementation).

This is the outline of a hand-rolled parametric bootstrap:

```
nboot <- 10
nresp <- length(FUN(orig_fit))
res <- matrix(NA,nboot,nresp)
for (i in 1:nboot) {
  res[i,] <- FUN(update(orig_fit,data=simulate(orig_fit,...)))
             ## or use refit() for LMMs
             ## ... are options to simulate()
}
t(apply(res,2,quantile,c(0.025,0.975)))
```

Comment: Thanks Ben, appreciate you looking in this and you have answered my question. I've added some extra detail on what I'm trying to do and would appreciate any further advice. Best wishes.

Comment: Thanks again. I was using across cores with snow but will do by hand as you suggest.

Comment: If you're feeling adventurous and have compilation tools installed you should be able to `devtools::install_github("lme4/lme4")` to install the development version, which I've just adapted to allow use of `re.form`  in `bootMer` ...